# What is the correct formula for Within Cluster Sum of Squares

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, euclidean-algorithm, clustering

I am studying clustering with K-Means algorithm and I got stumbled in the "inertia", or "within cluster sum of squares" part. First I would appreciate if anyone could explain me the difference between this two terms or if they are the same.
The problem I faced was when searching for the within cluster sum of squares on google images and finding this formulas:

$WSS\:=\:\sum _{i=1}^{N_c}\:\sum _{x\in C_i}^{ }\:d\left(x,\:\overline{x}_{C_{_i}}\right)^2$

From this image: [img 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6ZFc.png)

$WCSS\:=\:\sum _{C_{_k}}^{C_n}\:\left(\sum \:_{d_i\:in\:C_i}^{d_m\:}\:distance\left(d_i,\:C_{_k}\right)^2\right)$

From this image: [img 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGU5T.png)

And lastly:

$WCSS\:=\frac{1}{N}\:\sum _{i=1}^K\:\sum \:_{j=1}^{n_i\:}\left(x_{ij}\:-\:\overline{x_i}\right)^2$

From this image:[img 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoxRI.png)

The last imagem even calls it "Total Within Cluster Sum Of Squares".

I know that the inertia formula for a single cluster is:

$\sum \:_{i=1}^{N\:}\left(x_i\:-\:C_{_k}\right)^2$

Which actually makes sense to me, so based on this first formula, the one from the first image is the one who makes more sense.

Comment: I hope you don't mind my replying to [your comment on a now-deleted question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77649001/#comment136899890_77649001): I don't know why you commented or expect opening/undeletion; you have clearly not acted on all the feedback. Following "What I could think of" or "I have seen some people write about" is not "following [a] published textbook/presentation". PS [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) PS Put all but only what is needed to ask in your post, with credit, not just at a link.

Comment: Thanks, @philipxy. I find it very difficult to get help on this platform since my question is almost "how to normalize a table for answers on forms that have multiple choice questions", and you guys sent me a link to a Wikipedia page explaining what normalization is. I searched for this problem and the only thing I could find was the link, not a textbook/presentation specific to my case. Anyway, I could figure it out with the help of a teacher of mine.